# Batch convert images with xargs & convert, how to name output file?

Tags: xargs, conversion

It's known that images can be converted to one single pdf with the following command (assuming images filenames are order correctly):

`convert *.jpg output.pdf`.

However, this approach may take too much RAM when it involves thousands images. Another idea would be converting images to pdf by batches, then concatenate the resulted pdf to a single one with `pdftk`:

`pdftk output-*.pdf cat output output.pdf`

So far, I tried to batch convert images with `xargs`:

`ls *.jpg  |  xargs -d $'\n' -t -n 100 bash -c 'convert "$@" output.pdf'`

It works well except that each time, `convert` erases the previous pdf.

**Question**: Is there a way to count the batch number, and produce successively, for instance, `output-1.pdf`, ..., `output-9.pdf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to swap `xargs` for GNU `parallel`, that *does* provide a `{#}` replacement string containing the sequence number being run.

So for example given

```
$ touch File{001..050}.jpg
```

then

```
$ printf '%s\0' *.jpg | parallel --null -n 5 echo convert {} -o output{#}.pdf
convert File001.jpg File002.jpg File003.jpg File004.jpg File005.jpg -o output1.pdf
convert File006.jpg File007.jpg File008.jpg File009.jpg File010.jpg -o output2.pdf
convert File011.jpg File012.jpg File013.jpg File014.jpg File015.jpg -o output3.pdf
convert File016.jpg File017.jpg File018.jpg File019.jpg File020.jpg -o output4.pdf
convert File021.jpg File022.jpg File023.jpg File024.jpg File025.jpg -o output5.pdf
convert File026.jpg File027.jpg File028.jpg File029.jpg File030.jpg -o output6.pdf
convert File031.jpg File032.jpg File033.jpg File034.jpg File035.jpg -o output7.pdf
convert File036.jpg File037.jpg File038.jpg File039.jpg File040.jpg -o output8.pdf
convert File041.jpg File042.jpg File043.jpg File044.jpg File045.jpg -o output9.pdf
convert File046.jpg File047.jpg File048.jpg File049.jpg File050.jpg -o output10.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, plus it's faster and concise.

Answer (score 1):

xargs doesn't provide a way to count the current instance. You could do `ls *.jpg  |  xargs -d $'\n' -t -n 100 bash -c 'convert "$@" output-$$.pdf'` to get different names, but then you'd have to figure out the order based on the file timestamp.

A solution would be to progressively combine them:

```bsh
ls *.jpg  |  xargs -d $'\n' -t -n 100 bash -c 'convert "$@" temp.pdf'; if [ -f output.pdf ]; then mv temp.pdf next.pdf; pdftk output.pdf next.pdf cat output temp.pdf; fi; mv temp.pdf output.pdf`
```

Although I think the best way for this would be to just convert each image individually:

```bsh
find -name \*.jpg -exec convert \{\} \{\}.pdf \;
pdftk *.jpg.pdf cat output output.pdf
```

It's simpler, and cost of converting every image on a separate process would be roughly equivalent to having one convert instance processing N of them.

Plus, if it happens that one of the images isn't actually ordered, it's simpler to rearrange, rather than having to reconvert every image since the batches now changed.

Comment: Ah, you're right and that's what I used to do actually. Probably was obsessed to write a one-liner. Thanks!